# How to pass value parameter in url that cannot excecute directly in url?

Tags: asp-classic

So i have this program that sending notification value to other page and show the notification, but the problem is you can edit the value in the url,

```
    If lngErrNo <> 0 Then
        response.write "Error while update Product."
        response.end
    Else
        v_strMsg = "Edit Kelipatan Jumlah Pesanan Berhasil!"
        
        Response.Redirect "global_notification.asp?strMsg=" & v_strMsg
    End If
```

the problem is you can edit v_strMsg in url for the example abc.com/global_notification.asp?strMsg= "anything you can edit the value here", and the display page is look like this

```
<body>
<table class="1" width=70%  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3" background="images/bgtable.gif"><div align="left" class="fontwhiteheader13">&nbsp;&nbsp;
              ATTENTION!!</div>
            </td>
  </tr>
          <tr>
           <td valign="top"><table width=100% height="360" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" bgcolor="white">
        
          <tr>
            <td align=center class="fontblueheader13"><%=Request.QueryString("strMsg")%>
            </td>
          </tr>
    </table></td></tr></table>
</body>
```

any possible way to sending the value without changing it to POST metod? i try htmlEncode but v_strMsg still can be edited in url, any suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a signed URL.

A signed URL includes a digital signature that proves the request was generated by the server.

The first thing you need to do is create a secret key:

```vb
' Generate your own key from:
' https://www.allkeysgenerator.com/Random/Security-Encryption-Key-Generator.aspx

Const secret_key = "G+KbPeShVmYq3s6v9y$B&E)H@McQfTjW"
```

In this example it's a 256 bit key.

You also need a hashing function:

**hash.asp**

```vb
<%

    ' Might as well store the secret key constant in this file:
    
    Const secret_key = "G+KbPeShVmYq3s6v9y$B&E)H@McQfTjW"

    Function Hash(ByVal Input, HashAlgorithm)
        
        ' Select the System.Security.Cryptography value.
        
        Select Case uCase(HashAlgorithm)
        
            Case "MD5"
            
                HashAlgorithm = "MD5CryptoServiceProvider"
                
            Case "SHA1"
            
                HashAlgorithm = "SHA1CryptoServiceProvider"
                
            Case "SHA2","SHA256"
            
                HashAlgorithm = "SHA256Managed"
                
            Case "SHA384"
            
                HashAlgorithm = "SHA384Managed"
                
            Case "SHA5","SHA512"
            
                HashAlgorithm = "SHA512Managed"
                
            Case Else
            
                HashAlgorithm = "SHA1CryptoServiceProvider"
        
        End Select
        
        ' Convert the input to bytes if not already.
                    
        If NOT VarType(Input) = 8209 Then
                        
            Dim utf8 : Set utf8 = Server.CreateObject("System.Text.UTF8Encoding")
            
                Input = utf8.GetBytes_4(Input)
                                                
            Set utf8 = Nothing
            
        End If
        
        ' Perform the hash.
                    
        Dim hAlg : Set hAlg = Server.CreateObject("System.Security.Cryptography." & HashAlgorithm)
        Dim hEnc : Set hEnc = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.DomDocument").CreateElement("encode")
            
            hEnc.dataType = "bin.hex"
            hEnc.nodeTypedValue = hAlg.ComputeHash_2((Input))
            Hash = hEnc.Text
                
        Set hEnc = Nothing
        Set hAlg = Nothing
        
    End Function

%>
```

Now you're ready to sign your URL with a digital signature.

```vb
' Be sure to include "hash.asp"

' Your message:
v_strMsg = "Edit Kelipatan Jumlah Pesanan Berhasil!"

' A unix timestamp:
v_uts = DateDiff("s","1970-01-01 00:00:00",Now())

' NOTE: Your servers timezone should be set to UTC to generate a true unix timestamp, 
' but it doesn't really matter, as long as "global_notification.asp" is on the same
' server, or a server set to the same timezone as the page you're generating the 
' signature from.

' Now we create the signature as so:
v_signature = Hash(v_strMsg & v_uts & secret_key,"SHA256")

' Finally, redirect to "global_notification.asp"
Response.Redirect "global_notification.asp?strMsg=" & Server.URLEncode(v_strMsg) & "&ts=" & v_uts & "&signature=" & v_signature
```

Example redirect:

> global_notification.asp?strMsg=Edit+Kelipatan+Jumlah+Pesanan+Berhasil%21&ts=1612794802&signature=61016c0a0460902cc4a19f092dcbb4fd818aa9c88d2631e087868253e73983da

Now to validate the signature on `global_notification.asp`:

```vb
<!--#include file = "hash.asp" -->
<%
    
    Dim v_strMsg, v_uts, v_signature, v_uts_now
    
    v_strMsg = Request.QueryString("strMsg")
    v_uts = Request.QueryString("ts")
    v_signature = Request.QueryString("signature")
    
    ' Do some basic validation first.
    
    If v_signature = "" Then
    
        Response.Write "Missing Signature"
        Response.End()
        
    ElseIf v_uts = "" Then
    
        Response.Write "Missing Timestamp"
        Response.End()
        
    ElseIf NOT Len(v_signature) = 64 Then
    
        Response.Write "Invalid Signature"
        Response.End()
    
    ElseIf NOT (IsNumeric(v_uts) AND Len(v_uts) = 10) Then
    
        Response.Write "Invalid Timestamp"
        Response.End()  
    
    End If
    
    ' Validate the signature. To do this, we simply recreate what we're expecting the signature
    ' to be, and compare it to the one being passed.
    
    If NOT Hash(v_strMsg & v_uts & secret_key,"SHA256") = v_signature Then
    
        Response.Write "Invalid Signature"
        Response.End()
    
    End If
    
    ' Now let's set an expiration period for the link, say 30 seconds? (or 86400 seconds for a day, 604800 for a week etc).
    
    v_uts = Int(v_uts) + 30
    v_uts_now = DateDiff("s","1970-01-01 00:00:00",Now())
    
    If v_uts_now >= v_uts Then
    
        Response.Write "Expired Link"
        Response.End()
    
    End If
    
    ' At this point, everything is good.
    ' Go ahead and display the message:
    
%>
<body>
<table class="1" width="70%"  cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td colspan="3" background="images/bgtable.gif"><div align="left" class="fontwhiteheader13">&nbsp;&nbsp;ATTENTION!!</div></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td valign="top"><table width="100%" height="360" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="2" bgcolor="white">
        <tr>
          <td align=center class="fontblueheader13"><%=v_strMsg%></td>
        </tr>
      </table></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
```

Now if you try and change the message (or the timestamp) you'll get an `Invalid Signature` error. The only way to generate a valid working link is to know the secret key, which of course is hidden.